# How to get UserId of current user in Custom Workflows of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-activity

I need userId of current user in Custom Workflows of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. So can you suggest me how to get it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), and that you created your custom workflow following [Create a Custom Workflow Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx) article from MSDN, it should inherit [CodeActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.codeactivity.aspx) class, 
and has a method like:

```cs
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
  // Your code here
}
```

To get the current `userId`, you need to obtain the `IWorkflowContext` from the `CodeActivityContext`, like this:

```cs
IWorkflowContext workflowContext = context.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
```

And then:

```cs
var id = workflowContext.UserId;
```

Comment: @Antonie: Hey thank you so much. Its working.<br />
And one more thing is that, we can also use below code to get userId:<br />
IExecutionContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IExecutionContext>();
Guid currentUserID = context.UserId;
Which one is more effictive..? 
And can we get the same using WhoAmIRequest and WhoAmIResponse classes..?

Comment: @Charan: I didn't try those, but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iexecutioncontext_members.aspx), it seems that IExecutionContext.UserId calls IWorkflowContext.UserId, so use the interface that best fits your needs. And concerning WhoAmIRequest/Response, the context already contains the information on the user, so making another request to obtain it seems too much for me.